# Varying input parameters in different processors

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, grid, openmpi

I have a program with varying Input parameters that should execute the same functions in the program. How can I make each set of Input parameters to work on different processors in the grid. Please help if you have even any little idea. Would really help a lot! Program is in C++

Comment: what do you mean by " work on different processors in the grid" ?

Comment: By different processors, do you mean like Athlon-64 and Intel iCore7, or do you mean PowerPC and x86? What are you trying to vary, why? [Another XY question, you are trying to solve problem X, think that Y is the solution, and ask how to do Y]

Comment: by different processors I mean, Different nodes on a grid environment. I am trying to distribute the work among various computers for fast calculation. So, I want to make each set of input parameters to run on each node. Am I clear enough?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what cluster resource manager you use. Most support so-called *array jobs*, where many instances of the same job are run and a parameter, usually a simple integer index of the current job, is passed via the environment. That's what we call the poor man's parallel computing platform :)

Since I have only extensively used *Sun Grid Engine* (now *Oracle Grid Engine*, also open-source forks under the name of [Open Grid Scheduler](http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/) and [Son of Grid Engine](https://arc.liv.ac.uk/trac/SGE) exist) and *Platform LSF* (now IBM LSF, also available as the very similar open-source [openlava](http://www.openlava.org/) job scheduler), I can only write about them (and to some extent about Torque).

With SGE an array job might looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
#$ -cwd
#$ -N jobname
#$ -t 1-100
## Other resource requirements
#$ -l h_rt=0:30:00
#$ -l h_mem=1200M
#$ -pe openmp 12

export OMP_NUM_THREADS=12
density=$((SGE_TASK_ID * 0.06))       # zsh specific
/path/to/executable -d density < input_${SGE_TASK_ID} > output_${SGE_TASK_ID}
```

Here the `-t 1-100` parameter to `qsub` creates an array job of 100 tasks, numbered from `1` to `100`. SGE passes the current task number in the `SGE_TASK_ID` environment variable. You can use it to select the appropriate input file or you can use it to compute other input parameters. SGE will automatically suffix both job's output and error files with the task ID. Note that using floating-point literals in `$(())` appears to be `zsh`-specific.

Array jobs in Torque are created exactly in the same manner as with SGE via the `-t` parameter. With Torque versions before 2.3 `-t` accepts one argument - the number of tasks, then numbers tasks from `0` to this number minus 1. Starting with Torque 2.3 one can specify ranges like with SGE:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
#PBS -N jobname
#PBS -l nodes=1,walltime=00:30:00
#PBS -t 1-100

cd ${PBS_O_WORKDIR}

export OMP_NUM_THREADS=12
density=$((PBS_ARRAYID * 0.06))       # zsh specific
/path/to/executable -d density < input_${PBS_ARRAYID} > output_${PBS_ARRAYID}
```

The main difference with SGE is that the task ID environment variable is named `PBS_ARRAYID`. See the [Job Submission](http://www.clusterresources.com/torquedocs21/2.1jobsubmission.shtml) part in the Torque manual.

With LSF an array job might looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

#BSUB -J jobname[1-100]
# Have separate error file for each job
#BSUB -e error_%I
# Other resource requirements, e.g.
#BSUB -W 0:30
#BSUB -M 1200
#BSUB -n 1
#BSUB -x

export OMP_NUM_THREADS=12
density=$((LSF_JOBINDEX * 0.06))       # zsh specific
/path/to/executable -d density < input_${LSF_JOBINDEX} > output_${LSF_JOBINDEX}
```

Here appending the range specification `[1-100]` after the job name creates an array job. LSF passes the task ID via the `LSF_JOBINDEX` environment variable. You can use it exactly the same way as in the SGE case.

Comment: Thank you for being so much kind to kind to give ma reply.

Comment: SO are u saying that in SGE ARRAY JOBS, each SGE_TASK_ID would work on different nodes of the grid? or should I specify it to use different nodes somewhere? and how can I use SGE_TASK_ID with different tasks to compute different Input parameters from the program?

Comment: Submitting and array job is as if many jobs with the same job file were submitted. It is up to SGE to decide where to execute each instance, based on the resources available and on the requirements of the individual job instance (in array jobs all instances have the same resource requirements). SGE provides you with the job number and you have to translate it to something useful. I have already showed you an example.

Comment: In SGE, does all outout files from different task id gets collected on a single folder by default or should it be mentioned somewhow? If so, How? And is there any book that you would suggest which could give me a detailed idea of this? Would be great help, Thanks!

Comment: The output from each task goes either to the home directory or to the one where `qsub` was executed, depending on whether `-cwd` was specified, and is stored in a file that is suffixed with the task ID. The [Oracle Grid Engine documentation archive](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/oem/grid-engine-166852.html) is a good place to start learning about it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify what parallel paradigm you use. MPI, OpenMP, something other.

Usually applied approach is to use some communication channel and send vectors of parameters from "main" process, to all others.

It is most common to broadcast parameters when they are the same, but main task can iterate over a set of them and send each one to each other task via 1 to 1 communicator.

Sometimes parameters are prepared in one or set of files and each task reads it's own set parameters.

Everything depends on the site your application is deployed and the scale of the job. I.e. when you have 1 million tasks for a job on super computer the file approach might be a bad idea.

Comment: task is the same but parameters are differnt which needs to run the same task. can you please be kind to explain in a more simpler language, I am a beginner in programming!

Comment: the program is already parallelized with Open MP to use all the threads in the node. But now I am trying to make the program run on different nodes itself. So,if I am not wrong, we are combining Distributed Memory and shared memory model.

Comment: What system do you use to send tasks to grid nodes? Is there any communication between tasks? You seem not to know what is going on. You say task is the same only different params. Then, I suppose there is no communication in-between them and introducing it would be overkill. On the other hand you say you suggest you do use distributed memory. Which is it ?